# Abrir accordion específico ao clicar numa lista

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, accordion

Meu problema é o seguinte:
Tenho uma lista (ul>li) que ao clicar numa delas, deve ir pra uma página onde contem os accordions específicos.

O site é esse: www.alfacontabil.com.br

Na página inicial tenho Serviços e Consultas, cada um com sua lista.

Ao clicar num item da lista, tem que ir pra página, mas com o conteúdo aberto.
Ex: Se clicar em Serviços > Para sua Empresa, na página específica o accordion deve vir com o conteúdo 'Para sua Empresa' aberto.

Comment: Então o usuário acha que está indo para a página do conteúdo A, mas nessa página tem um accordion com o conteúdo A, B e C?

Não seria melhor efetivamente _dividir_ esses conteúdos?

Pra fazer isso que você quer, você vai ter que adicionar um listener no evento "load" da página, e nele verificar se uma âncora (#) foi especificada. Se foi, tem que ocultar a aba padrão do accordion, e em seguida mostrar a aba correta... Vale a pena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema com o seguinte script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        //Get the selected accordion index, based on the URL hash.
        var index = jQuery('#tabs h3').index(
            jQuery('#tabs h3 a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]')
            .parent());

        //The index will be -1 if there is no hash in the URL.  This
        //is necessary if we want the first section expanded by default.
        if (index < 0){
            index = 0;
        }

        //The change event handler will add the hash to the URL when
        //a section is selected.
        var change = function(event, ui){
            window.location.hash = ui.newHeader.children('a').attr('href');
        }

        //Build the accordion, using the URL hash selection and the
        //change event handler.
        jQuery('#tabs').accordion({
            active: index,
            change: change,
            collapsible: true
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar este código em cada página uma vez que têm o hash/url bem defenido e igual à ancora:

```
var hash = window.location.hash; // ir buscar a string no url, por exemplo #para-sua-empresa
var esteHash = jQuery('#tabs [href="' + hash + '"]').index(); // saber que posição essa ancora com o nome que o hash capturou tem
jQuery("#tabs").accordion( "option", "active", esteHash ); // abrir a opção com o valor pretendido
```

Comment: Olá sérgio, não consegui fazer usando seu exemplo.